# Cucumber: can I access the Scenario Outline row object

Tags: cucumber, scenarios

I'd like to do something like this:

`Scenario Outline: create
    When I create < row >
    Then I should receive a code of < code >
    Examples:
        | name | height | eyecolor | code |
        | Bob  | 5'2"   | green    | 200  |
        | Ted  | 4'9"   | blue     | 200  |`

And then in my step def, for when I create, I want to be able to use the entire row to create the record.  Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Have you considered using lists? https://cukes.info/step-definitions.html

Answer (score 1):

Scenario Outline: create

```
 When I create < row >
    | < name > |
    | < height > |
    | < eyecolor > |
    | < code > |
    Then I should receive a code of < code >
    Examples:
        | name | height | eyecolor | code |
        | Bob  | 5'2"   | green    | 200  |
        | Ted  | 4'9"   | blue     | 200  |
```

Add the list under "When"
In the "When I create" step def use the DataTable as parameter to access the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You can have a singleton class that simulate the record, and in each iteration of the scenario build the record.